# function Executes Completely before next line of code.

Tags: ios, swift3

I have this code in my viewController. Problem is that when two functions called to load all data in CKRecord Object. Next Line of Code execute and prints 0 as record count. I want Swift to wait to for both functions to complete and then print their count. Help needed to solve this issue.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view1.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view1.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    loadNewData()     // function that loads all partyAccounts
    fetchPartyAccounts() // function to load all transactions

    print(loadTransactionData.count)
    print(partyAccountsData.count)
}

func loadNewData() {
    let qry = CKQuery(recordType: "PartyAccounts", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    qry.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Party_ID", ascending: true)]
    publicDB.perform(qry, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let rcds = results {
                self.partyAccountsData = rcds
            }
        }
        if error != nil {
            self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

func fetchPartyAccounts() {
    let qry = CKQuery(recordType: "Transactions", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    qry.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Party", ascending: true)]
    publicDB.perform(qry, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let rcds = results {
                self.loadTransactionData = rcds
            }
            if error != nil {
                self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: *Don't ask, tell*. Learn to understand how asynchronous methods work. Put the print lines at the end of the completion blocks respectively. And put the lines to reload the table view also **into** the completion blocks (inside the dispatch blocks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view1.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view1.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    loadNewData(){
         print(partyAccountsData.count)
    }     // function that loads all partyAccounts
    fetchPartyAccounts() {
         print(loadTransactionData.count)
    } // function to load all transactions

   // print(loadTransactionData.count)
   // print(partyAccountsData.count)
}

func loadNewData(callback:@escaping () -> Void) {
    let qry = CKQuery(recordType: "PartyAccounts", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    qry.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Party_ID", ascending: true)]
    publicDB.perform(qry, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let rcds = results {
                self.partyAccountsData = rcds
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                callback()
            }
        }
        if error != nil {
            self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
    }


}

func fetchPartyAccounts(callback:@escaping () -> Void) {
    let qry = CKQuery(recordType: "Transactions", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    qry.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Party", ascending: true)]
    publicDB.perform(qry, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let rcds = results {
                self.loadTransactionData = rcds
                callback()
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
            if error != nil {
                self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is showing error saying - parameter callback() is implicitly non escaping. when i click fix-it it changes callback:() -> Void to callback:@escaping () -> Void

Comment: @Aakash you are right, does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this..

```
variable_A= your_First_Function()     
variable_B=  your_Second_Function() 
print(variable_A)
print(variable_B
```

hope this will solve your problem. Although not sure but you can give it a try. Do let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for Help but it stills returns 0 as per your method.